# PDO prepaired statement UPDATE not working

Tags: forms, pdo, sql-update

I've been persistently trying to get this statement to update my db, but with no success. I have a form that is to allow user to update their username and email. What am I overlooking?

Here is my statement:

```
<?php require_once('config.php');
  $id= $_SESSION['id'];//get user id you can use session also
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $email    = $_POST['email'];
               $query = "UPDATE members SET username  = :username  ,email = :email WHERE id = :id";
             $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
             $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id"; //Get user info
    $stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        // output data of each row
     foreach($result as $row){
         $username =   $row['username'];
         $email    =  $row['email'];

      }

  }
?>
```

Here is my form:

```
<form role="form" class="cf-form floating-labels" method="post" action="<?php filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS); ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My Account<br />        
      <img class="logo_contact" src="img/jobmiser_logo2.png" alt="jobmiser logo" />
        </legend>
        <div class="icon">
            <label class="cf-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="user" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>" tabindex="2" required />
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <label class="cf-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" tabindex="3" required />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="icon">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" />
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Consider adding some code to log or emit error messages, and it's a bit suspicious to see three placeholders in your sql statement and only 2 `bindParam`s...

Comment: It seems your `UPDATE members` query is missing a binding of ":id" and you never execute it either!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the :id parameter in your update query:

```
// bind :id
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// You also need to execute it
$stmt ->execute();
```

In the second statement you should also bind the value id and not insert it directly into the string.

```
// BAD
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id"; 

// GOOD
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = :id"; //Get user info
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->execute();
```